# White noise mixing 2 audio byte array

Tags: java, audio, byte

I'm mixing 2 audio bytes arrays getting the mix with some white noise.

```
for (int i=0;i<bytes1.getB1().length;i++){
        mixBytes[i]=(byte) (bytes1[i]+bytes2[i]);
    }
```

Anyone knows how to solve the white noise problem ?

I'm getting the bytes with this method, removing the 44 first bytes as wav header.

```
private byte[] getISByteArray(InputStream is){
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int length;
    try {
        while ((length = is.read()) != -1) {
            stream.write(length);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    byte[] b=stream.toByteArray();
    byte[] b2=new byte[b.length-44];
    //System.arraycopy(b, 44, b2, 0, b2.length);
    for (int i=0;i<b.length;i++){
        if (i>44) b2[i-44]=b[i];
    }
    return b2;
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see two potential problems immediately:

- You're treating the inputs as if they were one-byte-per-sample streams. Are they really?
- You're not doing anything about overflow, which will take two bytes of value 100 and end up with a negative number for example.

For the latter, this *might* help - although it depends on whether the bytes are really linear amplitude etc, just by taking the average:

```
mixBytes[i]=(byte) ((bytes1[i]+bytes2[i]) / 2);
```

I suspect that will make it *slightly* better, but it's still not a great mixing function...

Comment: How can I solve the overflow problem ? I mean, if the result of the addiction is negativa, what value must have ?

Comment: I'm getting the byte with this method...I edited the original post

Comment: @Fischer: the averaging code I gave should fix that have you tried it?

Comment: Jon, If I divide by 2 only one array of bytes, and play only this array without mix i get noise.

Comment: How can I test if they are one-byte per sample ?

Comment: @Fischer: You should know based on the audio format you're trying to use. We have basically no idea what you're doing here, other than the byte manipulations.

Comment: Well... The files are .wav and bitrate = 1411kbps

Comment: I think you're still going to get overflow with that code before you do the divide by 2. What you actually need is : mixBytes[i]=(byte) (((int)bytes1[i]+(int)bytes2[i]) / 2);

Comment: @Redeye: No, because the bytes are promoted to ints before the arithmetic is performed anyway.

Comment: OK, I have been researching and I thought the problem was cause the little- endian encoding of wav files in 16 bits. But I tried to convert each two pairs of bytes into short to handle better, but I receive the same noise.

Comment: Note that I receive not only noise, i receive the sound with some noise

Comment: @Fischer: Perhaps you aren't converting them to shorts properly then - or possibly not *back* properly. It's hard to see without any code. But why don't you use the Java Sound API instead of doing this manually?

Comment: Cause it's for android. Ok , i found the problem. As you say, it's due to a bad convertion to short. Thank you!

Comment: @Fischer: This is a good example of why it's important to give context in your question - this is the first time you've mentioned anything about Android. I suspect there are audio APIs for Android anyway... glad you've sorted things though.

Comment: Yes, there are audio APIs for Android, but the only way I can get good accuracy for doing what I need is to mix the audio bytes for playing with audioTrack class.

Answer (score 0):

Convolve your original signal with a low-pass [Gaussian filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function) and you will remove the white noise.

Comment: The original bytes doesn't have noise. It's a problem with the mix method.